# Google Maps GeoCoding always uses browser language

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-api

I am using the Google AJAX API loader and want to get all the information in German so I am loading the maps API like this

```
google.load("maps", "2", {language : "de"});
```

I have tried `deu`, `ger`, `de`, `de_DE` and even en and `ja_JPbut` no success.

For those who don't understand my problem:
http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/5910/Jing/2008-11-24_2018.png you can try it at http://apps.komola.de/gmaps.htm the address in English on the English browser and German on the German browser

Answer (score 3):

This API doc indicates the limitations of the map localization http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/#Localization

The language appears to just affect the interface (buttons etc), base_domain affects which services it uses.  So base_domain forces it to use google.de for the geocoding service.

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=KEYHERE" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     google.load("maps", "2",{language: "de",base_domain: 'google.de'});
     ...
</script>
```

The loader doc mentions the base_domain. 
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#GoogleLoad

Comment: Not working for me :( I am using an english client(firefox) but my german IE shows it in german if I say language: 'en' it still shows me the german response

Comment: I tested it using FF2/FF3 and IE6 with success with en/fr/de. Is any of the interface in showing up in the language you set?

Comment: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/5910/Jing/2008-11-24_2018.png you can try it at http://apps.komola.de/gmaps.htm the geolocation is english on the english browser..

Comment: I think I found it. Add {base_domain: 'google.de'} to the load params.